# Convert string to int in c

Tags: c, linux, string, multidimensional-array, strtol

What I am trying to do is to access a string value in a multidimensional string array in C. The string is actually a number value which I want to store in an integer value.

When I try to print the value as following

```
  printf("TESTING COMMAND\n");
  printf("%d\n",commands[0][0]);
```

The value prints the normal expected value

However when I try to use it to initialize an array for example as below

```
  char **options[ (x - 1) ];
```

This gives the following error

```
  error: size of array ‘options’ has non-integer type
```

Which I expect because the command array is declared as following

```
  char ***commands;
```

The thing is that even if I try to assign an integer variable to hold this value I get a segmentation error

```
 x = command[0][0];
```

I have also tried functions like `strtol` which led to the same result. However I am not sure if I have used the function right.

Any suggestions ?

```
int x;
printf("TESTING COMMAND\n");
printf("%d\n",commands[0][0]);
x = command[0][0];
printf("Creating options of size = %d\n", x );
```

Comment: Post more code, not just tiny fragments

Comment: `printf("%d\n",commands[0][0]);` What is command, how is it defined/declared?

Comment: @wildplasser commands is define as char ***commands;

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix that is the code where I try to assign the integer to a variable int x;

  printf("TESTING COMMAND\n");
  printf("%d\n",commands[0][0]);
  
  x = command[0][0];
  printf("Creating options of size = %d\n", x );

Comment: @Abdel-RahmanShoman Is there any good reason to present the code in reversed order? I like to read top to bottom. (and so does my compiler)

Answer (score 0):

Try the sscanf formatting function.

It works like - void sscanf(char *arr, "format-specifier", address of var  to store the formatted value.)

For eg :
  say we have - char *arr = "123"
  declare int val;

then-
sscanf(arr, "%d", &val);
val will equal 123.

Comment: Could you please format your answer a bit better to make it more readable? Thank you

Answer (score -1):

The function you're looking for is probably `atoi()`:

```
x = atoi(commands[0][0]);
```

It parses the string as a number and returns it as an `int`. You'll need to include `stdlib.h`.

Comment: since `atoi()` has no way of reporting errors, and it invokes undefined behavior upon overflow, its use is discouraged – please do **not** recommend it. A more modern alternative is `strtol()`.

Comment: In the vast majority of situations there isn't much reason to care about those shortcomings, however, and it *is* simpler to use. :)

Comment: carelessly ignoring error conditions is unprofessional because it is dangerous. Do not encourage doing it!

Comment: It's not like it causes security problems, crashing or other reliability issues. It is not necessarily meaningful to report every user mistake in every piece of software.